# Drop down with predefined values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- How will i add predefined values to a collection_select? Like...
  US
  UK
  AUS
  PAK

Comment: you may check: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635495/select-amongst-predefined-values-for-a-t-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `collection_select` helper is used for when you want the options within the select element to come from a collection of ActiveRecord models. For your requirements you should use the `select` helper in combination with `options_for_select`:

```
<%= select(:country, :country_id,
  options_for_select([['US', 1], ['UK', 2], ['AUS', 3], ['PAK', 4]])) %>
```

- [select API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002302)

Comment: what are these :id and :name for? it gives me the error... undefined method `name' for ["US", 1]:Array