# Select amongst predefined values for a t.string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Is it possible to create a

```
collection_select
```

or

```
select tag
```

for a

```
t.string
```

Where a user can select amongst predefined values for the string and only those values allowed to be stored in the database for the string? For example

```
t.string :relationship_status
```

And I want predefined values:

```
In a relationship
Single
Maried
Engaged
ETC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork) is along the lines of:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = [
    "single",
    "in a relationship",
    "together",
    "it's complicated"
  ]

  validates :relationship_status, :inclusion => RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES
end
```

Then later, in the view:

```
collection_select(:person, :relationship_status, Person::RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES, :to_s)
```

This produces:

```
<select name="person[relationship_status]">
  <option value="single">single</option>
  <option value="in a relationship">in a relationship</option>

  ...
</select>
```

Comment: I get ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)):

Comment: In your case, the value you want is the same as the id, so you can just use `to_s`.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `permission' for #<Permission:0x00000005620408>): and I used <%= f.collection_select(:permission, :user_about_me_mockup, Permission::MOCKUP_PERMISSIONS, :to_s) %> in my simple_form

Comment: I 'll mark this as correct because it's my fault that I am using simple_form instead the regular form helper. Thanks.